# Why HttpStatusCodeException is not caught when a 400 is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

cConsider the below class, when a 400 BAD_REQUEST is thrown by the rest call, I expect the HttpStatusCodeException to get caught, but instead it catches unexpected error Exception and throws an Internal Server Error. Why is HttpStatusCodeException not caught when a "BAD_REQUEST" is thrown?

```
 class Abc {
    
     @Autowired
     RestTemplate template;
    
     
     void connect(){
    
        ResponseEntity<String> response;
    
        try{
            response=restTemplate.postForEntity("url", HTTP_ENTITY, String.class);
    
        } catch( HttpStatusCodeException ex){
             throws new CustomErrorResponse(ex.getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception ex){
             throws new CustomErrorResponse(Internal_Server_Error);
        }
      }
    
    }
```

**JUnit Testcases**

```
 when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),eq(String.class))).thenThrow(new CustomErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```

**But Internal Server is thrown**

Comment: Print/log the stack trace from `Exception ex`, instead of discarding `ex` - and then you should see what specific exception is being thrown. (`HttpStatusCodeException` is an abstract class.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test case with restTemplate then `throws CustomErrorResponse` not `HttpStatusCodeException`

Solution:

```
when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),eq(String.class))).thenThrow(new HttpStatusCodeException(..));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `connect` method can have a different return type, the easiest way would be to return a `ResponseEntity` and pass the status code in to that.

```
     ResponseEntity<Object> connect(){
    
        ResponseEntity<String> response;
    
        try{
            response=restTemplate.postForEntity("url", HTTP_ENTITY, String.class);
    
        } catch( HttpStatusCodeException ex){
             response = new ResponseEntity<>("There was an issue with the POST call.", ex.getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception ex){
             throws new CustomErrorResponse(Internal_Server_Error);
        }
        return responseEntity;
     }
```